# how to get the httparty call return something inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

```
[{"Id"=>1015765, "Date"=>"/Date(1468062000000+0100)/", "EventGroupName"=>"Electric Daisy Carnival", "VenueName"=>"Milton Keynes Bowl", "Town"=>"Milton Keynes", "Country"=>"UK", "TicketCount"=>35, "Currency"=>"GBP", "MinPrice"=>79.75, "LayoutId"=>3932, "EventGroupId"=>32347, "VenueId"=>3596}]
```

I'm getting this response form an api im calling

How do i go about getting the id to use elsewhere in the controller???

Heres my controller

```
api = HTTParty.get("url here").parsed_response
id = api["Events"]
```

I have tried sticking  `[Id]` on the end of the `id` call but that didnt work.

Sam

**Additional**

Heres what i tried :)

```
id = api["Events"].first["Id"]
    results = HTTParty.get("partoneofurl" + id + "parttwoofurl")


 syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' 

 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `HTTParty` call is an array that contains a hash table with the response elements. To access the these values you need first to access the hash table, that is the array's first element and then you can access the values in the hash table. You can do that in this way:

`$ api.first["Key"]`